# How To Pass Parameter in javascript find function?

Tags: javascript

Hie,

I have a json object which have a id field:

```
document = {
             id: 'some value',
             ...
           }
```

And a list to store this documents.

```
var list = [{document}, {document} ...]
```

Now I am trying to call javascript find() function on the list to return the document with a specific id as

```
list.find( document, id) => {
   if (document.id == id)
   return id
}
```

But its not working. I checked and found that the id parameter value is not what I am passing but the index value of the document in the list. I tried changing the name hoping it was a error with keyword but the sae result.

So, How do I pass a custom parameter to the find function?

Comment: You can't, but you should not need to. You can simply refer to the value in the body of the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a call back method that allows you to reference to variables outside of the scope of the callback.

Example:

```
var id = 10;
var foundDoc = list.find((document) => document.id == id);

// alternative syntax
var foundDoc = list.find((document) => {
  return document.id == id;
});
```

---

*In your example [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) takes a predicate that should return true/false if there is a match. On the first occurance of `true` (a match) that item is returned to the caller.*

Comment: @sam23 - glad to help.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a function which takers the parameter you want to use and returns a function to use as your find callback
e.g.

```js
function findCreator(id) {
   return (item) => item.id === id;
}

let items = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
let matchedItem = items.find(findCreator(2));
console.log(matchedItem);
```

This would be ideal for testing as you can now test the callback separately

Answer (score 6):

> So, How do I pass a custom parameter to the find function?

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) accepts a second parameter `thisArg`. You can use it to pass custom parameters as follows:

```js
function finder(doc) {
   return doc.id === this.id;
}

let list = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
let doc = list.find(finder, {id: 2});
console.log(doc);
```

If there is no specific need for such a contrived setup however, you should rather go with the much simpler `list.find(doc => doc.id === 2)`. You can replace the hardcoded `2` with a variable declared in the outer scope as demonstrated in [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392050/1647737).